# Какие есть варианты аутентификации кошелька?

Tags: веб-программирование

Подскажите пожалуйста, какие есть варианты сделать аутентификацию (подключить кошелёк) крипты на сайте? Ну типа будет кнопка "подключить кошелёк"
В гугле искал web3.js, но там только react node js. Можно ли сделать на нативном js или с помощью php?

Answer (score 0):

[web3auth.io](https://web3auth.io/) предоставляет аутентификацию c [jwt токеном](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication). Или, можно использовать MetaMask и [электронную подпись строк](https://github.com/react-declarative/erc20-payment-gateway)

```js
const personalSign = async (message: string): Promise<string> => {
    const account = await this.getAccount();
    return await window.ethereum.request({
        params: [message, account],
        method: "personal_sign",
        from: account,
    });
};
```